# ExtJs Layout:How to arrange items in each line?

Tags: layout, extjs, vbox

I am a beginner of extjs.

I want to arrange some TextFields as below:

a:______    b:______    c:______

    d:______    e:______    f:______

here are my test codes below:

```
Ext.onReady(function()
{
    new Ext.panel.Panel(
    {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout:'vbox',
        width: 670,
        tbar: [{text:"Add"}],
        defaults:
        {
            layout:"column",
            height:50
        },
        items:
        [
            {
                defaults:
                {
                    labelAlign:"right",
                    labelWidth:50
                },
                items:
                [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'a'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'b'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'c'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                defaults:
                {
                    labelAlign:"right",
                    labelWidth:50
                },
                items:
                [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'd'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'e'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'f'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

as a result, the page can't display any TextFields.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: See the example code http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/form/dynamic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
new Ext.panel.Panel({
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  width: 670,
  tbar: [{
    text: "Add"
  }],
  defaults: {
    layout: ,
    height: 50
  },
  items: [{
    defaults: {
      labelAlign: "right",
      labelWidth: 50
    },
    items: [{
      xtype: 'textfield',
      fieldLabel: 'a'
    }, {
      xtype: 'textfield',
      fieldLabel: 'b'
    }, {
      xtype: 'textfield',
      fieldLabel: 'c'
    }]
  }, {
    defaults: {
      labelAlign: "right",
      labelWidth: 50
    },
    items: [{
      xtype: 'textfield',
      fieldLabel: 'd'
    }, {
      xtype: 'textfield',
      fieldLabel: 'e'
    }, {
      xtype: 'textfield',
      fieldLabel: 'f'
    }]
  }]
});
```

It is essentially your same example except replacing the `vbox` layout with the default `auto` layout.  The reason why you example didn't work is that `vbox` layouts need a height and width set on it somehow.

You could also do something like :

```
new Ext.panel.Panel({
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  layout: 'column',
  width: 670,
  tbar: [{
    text: "Add"
  }],
  defaults: {
    labelAlign: "right",
    labelWidth: 50
  },
  items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'a'
  }, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'b'
  }, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'c'
  }, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'd'
  }, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'e'
  }, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'f'
  }]
});
```

It is a `column` layout without the nested items as the one before.  One nice thing about a `column` layout is that it will shift as many items as it can to the left and if an item can't fit it will go in the next row.
Since the width is a static 670 it can only fit 3 text fields per row.  Column layouts do not need a height set.

Comment: `vbox layouts need a height and width` +1 Didn't know this.

Comment: Thank you, I misstood the usage of the "vbox".